Minimizing a function with constraints
I have the following expression for the upper bound of the error produced from an algorithm  for computing $e^x$. There are three parameters ($M$, $N$, and $K$) that can be tuned in the algorithm to give more or less accuracy. Each of the parameters contributes to the overall number of computations in different ways. So my goal is to find the optimal combination of $M$, $N$, and $K$ that minimizes the  number of operations while also keeping the error under some value. The inequality for the upper bound of the error is ...
$$
\frac{\ln(2)}{2(N+3)}\left(\frac{\ln(2)}{2^{M+1}}\right)^{N+2} + \frac{\sqrt{2}}{(K+1)!}\left(\frac{\ln^{2}(2)}{2^{M+1}}\right)^{K+1} \leq 2^{-A-1}
$$
... where $A$ is the input for the accuracy that the algorithm needs to produce. The total number of operations that will be done for some $M$, $N$, and $K$ is as follows...
$$
M + 2N+2K-1 = F, \quad  M,N,K \in \mathbb{N}
$$
So my goal is to find an expression in terms of $A$ for $M$, $N$, and $K$ such that $F$ is minimized and the constraint on the first equation is satisfied.
